# Image Uri is not working as a props in react native

Tags: react-native

hello i am new to react native i use a library for slider react-native-flatlist-slider problem is for local image path its not working, its work when I give  https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567226475328-9d6ba here is picture how its work fine
[image]

but when I change this path to local require(''../assests/Phone-call.png'') its start to through an error here is the picture
[image]
here is my code

```
const images = [
    {
      image: require('../../assests/Phone-call.png'),
      heading: 'Order any where',
      desc:
        '"Praesent tellus mauris, tincidunt nec ipsum id, faucibus pellentesque leo. Nunc congue ac tellus quis porttitor. "',
    },
    {
      image: require('../../assests/Phone-call.png'),
      heading: 'Order any where',
      desc:
        'Praesent tellus mauris, tincidunt nec ipsum id, faucibus pellentesque leo. Nunc congue ac tellus quis porttitor. ',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatListSlider
        data={images}
        height={240}
        timer={5000}
        onPress={item => alert(JSON.stringify(item))}
        component={<Preview />}
        contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 0}}
        indicatorContainerStyle={{marginRight: 'auto'}}
        indicatorActiveWidth={30}
        animation
      />
    </View>
  );
```

preview component code

```
const Preview: React.FC<{}> = ({
  style,
  item,
  imageKey,
  onPress,
  index,
  active,
  local,
}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.videoContainer]}
        onPress={() => onPress(item)}>
        <View style={[styles.imageContainer]}>
          <Image style={[styles.videoPreview]} source={{uri: item[imageKey]}} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Title title="Order anywhere" />
          <SubTitle amount color="#06B2BC" title={item.desc} />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
<Image style={[styles.videoPreview]} source={{uri: item[imageKey]}} />
```

to this

```
<Image style={[styles.videoPreview]} source={item[imageKey]} />
```

The catch here is that...the `<Image />` component has a prop `source` which takes location of image as value..

So if the image is a `url` for example - `https://something_exmaple.com/test.png`
Then the `source` property will be written like this

`source={{uri: URI_LINK}}`

And if its a static file you want to load then you would have to write something like this

`source={require(./paht.to/image)}`

Check [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/image-source-correct-way) Snack that I made...It will help you.